# jQuery dialog box opens on click, but autoOpen not working

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a site [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/dev/cloud/)...

When you arrive at the site...

`autoOpen: true,` is working, but it's not loading the ajax request (jquery-ajax.html).

But, if you click the button at the top-left, that says "Compliance & Ethics", then the ajax request goes through and opens the dialog.

**What am I doing wrong, that it doesn't autoOpen properly?**

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 750,
        height: 'auto',
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        position: {my: "center top", at:"center top", of: window },
        buttons: {
            "Dismiss": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Here's what calls the ajax request on click...**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#dialog').load('jquery-ajax.html').dialog('open'); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went over your pages sourcecode and perhaps the reason is, that your function call happens before the div-box is created in the DOM. Also, you wouldn’t need to set the dialog `autoOpen` since you call `dialog('open')` by hand.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery('#dialog').load('jquery-ajax.html').dialog();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok. I fixed my function calls and fixed your other recommendation. It is still not working. Here's an updated site, if you could have a look again, I'd appreciate it. I would submit a fiddle, but I'm not sure how to replicate the error with the ajax calls.

Comment: I think you didn’t... ;) Set the `#dialog`-<div> to `autoOpen:false` and put the above code, which I posted, to your `<head>` section.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you said I had to get rid of the above script, or set autoOpen to false. My bad. Working on it now.

Comment: I see, that you renamed `#dialog` into `#compliance`, so you will have to adjust this, of course.

Comment: Ok. It's in there, just before the `</head>` tag. `autoOpen: false` is set. Still not working though. Any other ideas?

Comment: Additionally, doing it by way of your suggestion forces the buttons to open the ajax requests in another browser window, and not a dialog.

Comment: try `dialog()` instead of `dialog('open')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37696/discussion-between-webfrogs-and-jotaen)

Comment: It didn't work, and again... it is forcing the ajax requests to open in another browser window, and not through the dialog. The page is currently the way you suggested though.